# Android automatic input to text field of messaging

Tags: android

I have created an app using jelly bean version 4.2, the issue is that I have to created an input field on submission of that values a message should be sent. I want to know how this input values can be automatically put in the text field of the message.
Can anyone please help me out in sorting this issues.

Comment: Can you add your code snippet whatever you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming(as no additional info is available) that you want to display some message, like a toast, which should contain the value of your text field.

You can use like:

EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textFieldID);

String value = text.getText().toString();

Then use this string as message in your toast or pass it as an argument!!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks Mitul Shrivastava,

Comment: My assignment statement is to "create an app in which the values will be entered in one activity, and those values have to be recorded and the message has to be sent for further guidance." The message should contain the values entered in the previous activities edit text. N the solution given by is already incorporated in the java file of the app.

Comment: If u have any other solutions kindly share it